# smooth curves with canvas along 2d points

Tags: canvas, graph, bezier

im trying to use a formular to make smooth lines along a 2d axis - using bezier curves AND Canvas. 
What i have [this](http://atomicircus.org/stack/curve.html) - isnt quite working.
When u see my link - its soooo close - but the formular just isnt enough.
PLS help! :)
Also I dont want to use a library like paper js.

Here is the main code:

```
function getControlPoints(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,sion){

    var d01=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x0,2)+Math.pow(y1-y0,2));
    var d12=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2)+Math.pow(y2-y1,2));

    var fa=sion*d01/(d01+d12);   // scaling factor for triangle Ta
    var fb=sion*d12/(d01+d12);   // ditto for Tb, simplifies to fb=t-fa
    var p1x=x1-fa*(x2-x0);    // x2-x0 is the width of triangle T
    var p1y=y1-fa*(y2-y0);    // y2-y0 is the height of T
    var p2x=x1+fb*(x2-x0);
    var p2y=y1+fb*(y2-y0);  
    return [p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y];
}
```

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31859/Draw-a-Smooth-Curve-through-a-Set-of-2D-Points-wit Specifically the multi-segment part towards the bottom should be the formula you're looking for.